# Search API autocomplete view mode template

Tags: 8, search

I got search api autocomplete setup and using the live results feature I was able to set it to use my `Search Autocomplete` view mode. I am trying to figure out what the twig template name would be. Any ideas? I don't see the twig debug suggestions. Guessing because its coming in via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, this was easier than I thought. Its `node--view-mode.html.twig` as you normally would. Not sure why I thought it'd be different. In my case this was `node--search-autocomplete.html.twig`. I will leave this here for anyone else wondering how to do this.